# C Access violation writing location scanf_s

Tags: c, string, pointers, printf, scanf

Here is my code:

```
main()
{
    char firstName[30], lastName[30];
    printf("What is your name? ");
    scanf_s("%s %s", firstName, lastName);
    printf("Your name is %s %s\n", firstName, lastName);
}
```

I tried using scanf but VS said it was deprecated and recommended scanf_s. I know that you use the &/pointer before the variables unless it is a string/char[] (which this is meant to be) and I really don't know what the error is. Maybe it's the method parameters? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Ignore their crusade to deprecate half the standard library. Still, you might use scanf_s here if you want. The important difference is that any `char*` is followed by the size of the buffer, including the terminator.

Comment: Anyway, if you want to learn C, the microsoft tools are a bad choice. Better try GCC or any other non-ancient C compiler.

Comment: Thanks. So is it safe to ignore deprecation warnings? And I'd like to be able to use a decent IDE (coming from IntelliJ for Java, Eclipse seems horrid to me, how's VIM? :D). Do Microsoft tools include VS?

Comment: @Deduplicator this is valid C11 `scanf_s` and other bounds checked functions are an optional implementation part of Appendix K

Comment: If you want to write portable code, microsoft deprecation warnings are mostly bogus.

Comment: @Mgetz: Yes, they succeeded in getting it into an optional annex, though they show no impetus to implement the 99 standard in the next few decades. Which makes their deprecation warning doubly annoying.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MS has a habit of replacing standard C functions with "safe" versions, scanf_s is one such implementation. The docs are here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx

I believe the error will go away if you make this change:

```
scanf_s("%s %s", firstName, _countof(firstName), lastName, _countof(lastName));
```

I also believe there's a way to get around their corruptions of the language, but I stopped using MSVC years ago for precisely this reason.

Comment: Better link to the C standard, optional section: [C99 with Technical corrigenda TC1, TC2, and TC3 included](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)

Comment: Or use `if (scanf("%29s%29s", firstName, lastName) != 2) /* error */;` which works on every C implementation since forever.

Comment: Thank you everyone. You were saying you stopped using MSVC; what do you use now? And why are these 'safe' methods corruptions? Pardon my questioning, I just want to know :)

Comment: Deduplicator, I do not think scanf_s is part of any ISO version of the C standard, hence my link to MS documentation.

Comment: They made it in an optional annex. Just search the standard I linked.

Comment: C11 in the normative annex (optional extensions).  K.3.5.3.4 The scanf_s function.  There may be subtle differences between this definition and MS version.

Comment: I usually use gcc. Whenever using MSVC you must maintain your own discipline to use standard C to write portable code. It has long been a problem that Microsoft's compiler makes it far too easy to write non-standard code. There is a way to use standard scanf which Deduplicator linked above with MSVC, I think it's a compiler switch like /W3.